# Converting a function using SSE SIMD

Tags: c, function, sse, simd

I have trying to evaluate a value using sse simd instructions within a function.

```
    double integrate (double from, double to,double* counter)
{

    __m128d sum=_mm_setzero_pd();
    __m128d val=_mm_setzero_pd();
    __m128d width;
    __m128d fr=_mm_set1_pd(from);
    __m128d t=_mm_set1_pd(to);
    __m128d one=_mm_set1_pd(1.0);
    __m128d a,b,c,step;
    double result=0,i=0;

    width=_mm_set1_pd((to-from)/1000);

    while(i<1000){
    step = _mm_loadu_pd(&counter[i]);
    a    = _mm_mul_pd(step,width);
    b    = _mm_add_pd(fr,a);
        val  = _mm_div_pd(one,b);   
    c    = _mm_mul_pd(val,width);
    sum  = _mm_mul_pd(sum,c);
    i=i+2;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<1000; i++) {
        result += sum[i];
    }

    return result;
}
```

It takes 3 parameters two of them are double,one of them is double pointer for passing an array to the funtion.The code i try to convert is this;

```
double integrate (double from, double to)
{
    double sum=0,val=0,width;
    int i;
    width=(to-from)/1000;

    for(i=1;i<1000;i++){    
    val=1/(from+(i*width));
    sum=sum+(val*width);
    }

    return sum;
}
```

The code evaluates a value but its not as i expected.As far as i can understand,my real problem is about this part;

```
step = _mm_loadu_pd(&counter[i]);
```

What i am trying to do is passing the numbers in array called counter(holds numbers from 0 to 999) into step vector 2 numbers everytime (e.g r0:0 r1:1,r0:2,r1:3) and evaluating the other stuff.What is the thing i am doing wrong ?

Comment: May I ask you why on earth you are trying to do this given that compiler generates a nice SSE code for that?

Comment: Because it is an assignment

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
step = _mm_loadu_pd(&counter[i]);
```

to:

```
step = _mm_set1_pd(counter[i]);
```